# Buck Converter Switching Pin and Voltage Output

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, switching-regulator

By using rohm's BD9G341AEFJ-LB buck switching regulator, we want to take 5V. In datasheet [BD9G341AEFJ-LB's datasheet](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/switching_regulator/bd9g341aefj-e.pdf)
the example circuit given like

[image]

But we had to try circuit that is in Image-2, because of component absencity. Before trying this circuit we simulated at PSPice and it worked well except of some current ripple.

[image]

When we powered circuit in real it gives us 24V at output despite Vin 24V, too. First question, despite we tried PSPice and worked problemless, why did we take this 24V? Does it components value?

And we tried to measure the LX pin with oscilloscope in ac coupling mode. The screen of oscilloscope is[image] (Forgive me I haven't better oscilloscope)

In dc coupling mode already oscilloscope gives us 24V DC. Second question, Is voltage ripple normal? And at the datasheet example circuit, by setting RT resistance to 47k ohm frequency can set 200kHz, that is, if we look to oscilloscope screen, should frequency equal to 200kHz? Or Is frequency is equal to 200kHz?

**Last situation as of 05 August**

According to last comments and ROHM technical service, I made these:

I found closest components values as possible like in  adviced circuit in the datasheet(Image-1) . At the end, I obtained circuit that in below and results.

[image]

And layout like that:
[image]

When I supplied VCC with 24V, there was a fluctuating in LX pin between 0 to 1 V during first 20 seconds . And then abruptly I saw 24V at output. Before soldering all components, I controlled again the board and there wasnt any short circuit or different situation.

According to ROHM technical service, when I said this situation to them. They wanted me remove schottky barrier diodes one lead if you use RB095B-90. But why this problem occurs, they didnt tell. Im waiting a response,again. I will inform in here.[image]

Comment: For a buck converter, when output approximately equals input, either the series-pass MOSFET is shorted or the feedback is incorrect and the buck is running open-loop at its maximum duty cycle. LX should show a square wave at the desired switching frequency, not a strange triangular waveform. Are you using an appropriate inductor (one rated for DC biasing and high-frequency operation)? How about D1, is it rated for fast operation as well?

Comment: To help provide an answer, please add a waveform of the LX pin and measure the voltage at the FB pin.

Comment: Dear @AdamLawrence thanks for your comment. According to our measurement, the resistance between LX and VCC pin while IC was soldered is 0.3 ohm like shorted as you said, while we controlled new one is more than 100k ohm.  About to inductor, I know only lower value than in datasheet's example.

Comment: Thanks for comment @mr_js, FB =  4.6V . If already LX gives 24 , according to calculation 24*2/(8.2+2) = 4.7 V. Sorry, I tried but my oscilloscope isnt compatible for showing LX.

Comment: Do you have any load on the output? Try with a load (~100mA). Maybe the regulator is working in discontinuous conduction mode (DCM), some regulators can still work in that mode, others not. Place a 100 Ohm resistor at the output and see if it can regulate as expected.

Comment: @AdamLawrence, if my mosfet was shorted, how could this happen? How can I fix this mosfet's situation?

Comment: @Big6 I tried with axial 150 ohm, it burned. I tried with 500 ohm, still gives 24V

Comment: Looks like your control loop may be unstable due to the incorrect value of the compensation resistor (3.3K instead of 10K).  Do you really not have a 10K resistor you could try?

Comment: @JohnD I realized I put edited picture of datasheet's example, forgive me for this.(I put true one) But yes you are right. I found the circuit that is in Image-2, in internet. I calculated output voltage, divider resistors of FB and EN, frequency resistor of RT, but I didnt look VC compensation components. According to calculation again, they must be 6800pF cap and ~10k resistor. I will fix all circuit, and tell you what did be about results. Thank you.

Comment: @JohnD I changed compensation loop components, but still gives 24V. As I said before, mosfet shorted. I will change all components with true ones. I will write here again the results. Thanks for your attentions.

Comment: Good luck, definitely seems like a damaged part, but fixing the control loop should help when you install a new one.